# NSGraphicsContext leaking memory on macOS console tool

Tags: swift, macos, core-graphics, nsimage

I am trying to create a small utility class that will help draw an array of images on top of each other. Currently, I have the following code

```
struct DrawingLayer {
   let image: NSImage
   let point: CGPoint
}

class DrawingHelper {

let offscreenRep: NSBitmapImageRep

init() {
    guard let offscreenRep = NSBitmapImageRep(bitmapDataPlanes: nil,
                                    pixelsWide: 2500,
                                    pixelsHigh: 2500,
                                    bitsPerSample: 8,
                                    samplesPerPixel: 4,
                                    hasAlpha: true,
                                    isPlanar: false,
                                    colorSpaceName: .calibratedRGB,
                                    bitmapFormat: .alphaFirst,
                                    bytesPerRow: 0,
                                    bitsPerPixel: 32) else { fatalError() }
    self.offscreenRep = offscreenRep
}



func draw(layers: [DrawingLayer], filename: String) {
   autoreleasepool {
        guard let ctx = NSGraphicsContext(bitmapImageRep: offscreenRep) else { fatalError("Failed to create context") }
        NSGraphicsContext.saveGraphicsState()
        NSGraphicsContext.current = ctx
        
        layers.forEach { layer in
            layer.image.draw(in: CGRect(origin: layer.point, size: CGSize(width: 2500, height: 2500)))
            
        }

        NSGraphicsContext.current = nil
        NSGraphicsContext.restoreGraphicsState()
        
        guard let data = offscreenRep.representation(using: .png, properties: [:]) else { fatalError() }
        do {
            try data.write(to: URL(fileURLWithPath: filename))
        } catch {
            fatalError("\(error)")
        }
    }

}
```

I am instantiating this class and I am passing in an array of DrawLayer for each image I want to draw. Each layer represents a small image I want to draw inside the final image. I have noticed that if I instantiate an NSGraphicsContext each time I call the draw function, the memory usage of my program is going up. On the Allocations profiling tool I can the ImageIO_PNG_Data object to be using more and more memory but nothing is caught on the Leaks.

**NB: I managed to resolve my issue by wrapping the creation of the NSGraphicsContext in an autorelease pool. I updated the original code.**

Comment: NSGraphicsContext.saveGraphicsState -> where is matching restoreGraphicsState?

Comment: Hello, thanks for pointing out this, I updated the code, I am calling restoreGraphicsState before getting the image data. It still have the same effect.

Comment: There is nothing else wrong with this code. If you calculate 2500x2500 image size in memory you get a huge memory requirement number. Maybe it's normal for your app use but i think if you use this for regular drawing it's wrong. I think I had the same problem as you and it was due to "representation(using: .gif, properties: [:])". If you hold the data pointer it won't be released.

Comment: Thanks for your response, it seems that if I comment out the call to "representation(using: .gif, properties: [:])" the memory does not go up. However, even if I add to the code "_ = representation(using: .gif, properties: [:])" and return an empty Data object from that function the memory does go up. I am wondering if there is a specific call I need to do to this representation data to release it. How did you solve it in your case?

Comment: I think write that data to disk so you can get rid of the data pointer. I think I gave up as it's macOS mess that is responsible.

Comment: Ah I managed to resolve it by wrapping everything in an autoreleasepool. I will update the original question. Thanks Marek H for your help

Comment: Use autorelease pool on the method calling draw. Do not write data to disk in drawing method. Such a bad practice. Use verbs like render in context e.g. it won't even return data. On top context will be created outside of render method. Implement render:in: within DrawLayer class. BTW why is it call DrawLayer (verb) instead of DrawingLayer (or something better).

Comment: Thanks for all of the suggestions, this is just an example code that was meant to demonstrate the problem.